# MySQL Sort By Column, Then Pull The Rest

Tags: mysql

I have a unique situation where I need to pull many records, but sort SOME at the top if they are considered "favorites"...but then I need to pull all the rest of the records below this group.

Can this be done in one query...or will I need two? Any examples?

Comment: Yes it can be done. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `order by` can have arbitrary expressions `order by (somefield  = 42 ) DESC, somefield`, would put all the '42' records at the beginning of the result set, and then the rest of the records afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom `Order By` with a `CASE/WHEN` clause:

Schema:

```
create table music
(   mId int auto_increment primary key,
    song varchar(100) not null
);

create table person
(   pId int auto_increment primary key,
    pName varchar(100) not null
);

create table person_owns_music
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    mId int not null,
    pId int not null,
    favorite int not null,
    rating int not null, -- 100 loves it. 0 hates it
    foreign key `pom_2_music` (mId) references music(mId),
    foreign key `pom_2_person` (pId) references person(pId)
);
-- truncate table person_owns_music;
insert music(song) values ('s1'),('s2'),('s3'),('s4'),('s5'),('s6');
insert person(pName) values ('p1'),('p2'),('p3');
insert person_owns_music(mId,pId,favorite,rating) values
(1,1,1,10),(2,1,1,100),(3,1,0,65),(4,1,1,15),(6,1,1,5),
(1,2,1,10),(2,2,1,100),(5,2,1,100);
```

Query:

```
SELECT pom.mId,m.song,pom.favorite,pom.rating 
FROM person_owns_music pom 
JOIN music m ON m.mId=pom.mId 
WHERE pom.pId=1 
ORDER BY CASE pom.favorite 
        WHEN 1 THEN 1 
        WHEN 0 THEN 2 
        END, pom.rating DESC; 
+-----+------+----------+--------+
| mId | song | favorite | rating |
+-----+------+----------+--------+
|   2 | s2   |        1 |    100 |
|   4 | s4   |        1 |     15 |
|   1 | s1   |        1 |     10 |
|   6 | s6   |        1 |      5 |
|   3 | s3   |        0 |     65 |
+-----+------+----------+--------+
```